# Can't get scandir to scan root directory

Tags: php

I've tried every path I can think of.

`''`
`'/'`
`'htdocs/'`

No matter what I try, I cant figure out how to scan the root directory.

So, how do you do it?

Current Code:

```
function pathing(){
    $files = scandir('/');

    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if ($file === '.' OR $file === '..') {

        } else {
            print_r($file . ' ');
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you running this in the context of a web server?  Your worker process might not have permissions.

Comment: $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

Comment: Can you post the code you are trying?  glob() or some other function?

Comment: Yes, it is on a web server. I'm gonna try the document_root now. For that to work does the file need to be in the root directory?

Comment: `$files = scandir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);` 
scandir can read any directory apache user has enough prvilege to do so.

Comment: No but you would need to have permissions to scan the root.  Have you tried running the file from the shell?  I copied/pasted your function and it worked as-is from the shell...

Comment: I'm gonna be honest, I don't know what a shell is lol. But when I used document_root it works perfectly!

Comment: @devlincarnate you should make the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm moving my comment to an answer in order to bring attention to the solution for others who stumble across this question.

The directory root location is accessible in the [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) array.

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and to everyone else! :)